# Can not send email through gmail with Apache Commons Email.

Tags: java, email, gmail, apache-commons-email

Can not send email through gmail with Apache Commons Email.What is the problem?

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
        email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
        email.setSmtpPort(587);
        email.setTLS(true);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("mymail@gmail.com", "mypassword"));
        email.setFrom("mymail@gmail.com");
        email.setSubject("TestMail");
        email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
        email.addTo("sendmail@gmail.com");
        email.send();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1242)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1267)
    at MailService.sendSimpleMail(MailService.java:51)
    at MailService.main(MailService.java:17)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 3):

> What is the problem?

```
Could not connect to SMTP host
```

(Copied directly from the exception output you seem to have ignored.)

Answer (score 1):

please set email.setDebug(true); 
and with this command you can know what is your exact problem
maybe you username and password wrong

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a regular Gmail account or Google Apps email account, it is possible that Gmail it is blocking the current domain. Please ensure that you have the enough permissions to send mail from other applications.